# Use previous cell value from the same column if an event is not present in different column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am going through a time series data base in pandas. When an event happens I want the column I am calculating to store the date from another column. If the event is not present I want it to use whatever was in the cell above in the same column. I have tried the following but I cannot get it to work

```
DB['TimeFlag'] = np.where(DB['Event'] == 10,DB['Time'],DB['TimeFlag'].shift())
```

I understand it is referencing itself, but its referencing a cell that should have already been calculated. This feels like there should be a very simple solution but I cannot find one. It is very easy to do in excel and I included a visual of what I want the code to do. Any suggestions?

[image: Simple Excel Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using ffill()?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

DB = pd.DataFrame({'Time':['12:00', '12:01','12:02','12:03', '12:04', '12:05'],
                   'Event': [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]})

DB['TimeFlag'] = np.where(DB['Event'] == 1, DB['Time'], np.nan)
DB['TimeFlag'] = DB['TimeFlag'].ffill()
```

Output:

```
    Time    Event   TimeFlag
0   12:00   1       12:00
1   12:01   0       12:00
2   12:02   0       12:00
3   12:03   0       12:00
4   12:04   1       12:04
5   12:05   0       12:04
```